# Where to mention schema name in connectionstring for postgreSQL?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, connection, connection-string, postgresql-9.3

There are multiple schemas in PostgreSQl of JHI_Configure database and i want to connect to my `Configurator` Schema and run my code first migration. Whenever i run my migration, by default it is creating tables in `Public` schema. How to provide the `Configurator` schema name in my connectionstring. My connectionstring is :

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
       "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=JHI_Configure; Port:5432; User ID=sa; Password=test1;Trusted_Connection=True;"
},
```